# Slack Bot with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, bots, slack, slack-api

Im new to nodejs and Im trying to build an slack bot for my team 
my problem is that i need to get an access token from our api server so that i can request and get data from it. 
i found that slack uses oauth for authenticate slack users in another servers but i really dont know how it works and how to use it 
I really appreciate that if anyone tell how my bot can get an access token form slack server and send it to my server api and my server api authenticate that access token with slack server and send me a token so that my bot can request 
sorry for my English Im not very fluent in that 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to read through a couple of things - first, how Slack uses OAuth, which is here: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth

You're then going to want to look at how to do the OAuth exchange with NodeJS. Here's a tutorial that might help you with that: https://stormpath.com/blog/talking-to-oauth2-services-with-nodejs

Once you have those two down, you can make use of something like Slack's Node SDK to do the heavy lifting for you: https://slackapi.github.io/node-slack-sdk/

Comment: Also! If you're only installing the app to your own workspace, you don't need to worry about the OAuth flow. You can just grab the OAuth token from the app's configuration pages. https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#installing_apps